# Tomcat Windows Service (Apache Commons procsrv) "The user name or password is incorrect"

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, winapi

I've spent 2+ days trying to get this to work and hope somebody might be able to point me in the right direction...

I am trying to run Tomcat 8 on Windows Server 2012 R2 as a service as a specific username.  Due to the complexity of my application I am directly running tomcat8.exe //IS/... instead of using the service.bat script.

When the service runs I get these errors in the commons log:

```
[2016-05-31 18:00:14] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1679) [ 3280] Commons Daemon procrun log initialized
[2016-05-31 18:00:14] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1683) [ 3280] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 64-bit) started
[2016-05-31 18:00:14] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1580) [ 3280] Debugging 'CertAccordServer' service...
[2016-05-31 18:00:14] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1374) [ 3280] Inside ServiceMain...
[2016-05-31 18:00:14] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:844 ) [ 3280] reportServiceStatusE: 2, 0, 3000, 0
[2016-05-31 18:00:14] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1127) [ 3280] Starting service...
[2016-05-31 18:00:14] [error] (rprocess.c:497 ) [ 3280] The user name or password is incorrect.
[2016-05-31 18:00:14] [error] ( prunsrv.c:1210) [ 3280] Failed to create process
[2016-05-31 18:00:14] [error] ( prunsrv.c:1210) [ 3280] The user name or password is incorrect.
[2016-05-31 18:00:14] [error] ( prunsrv.c:1536) [ 3280] ServiceStart returned 1
[2016-05-31 18:00:14] [error] ( prunsrv.c:1536) [ 3280] The user name or password is incorrect.
[2016-05-31 18:00:14] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:844 ) [ 3280] reportServiceStatusE: 1, 1066, 0, 1
[2016-05-31 18:00:14] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1582) [ 3280] Debug service finished with exit code 1
[2016-05-31 18:00:14] [error] ( prunsrv.c:1755) [ 3280] Commons Daemon procrun failed with exit value: 3 (Failed to run service as console application)
[2016-05-31 18:00:14] [error] ( prunsrv.c:1755) [ 3280] The user name or password is incorrect.
```

Here is the full command I use to add the service:

```
./tomcat8.exe \
  //IS//MyServer \
 --LogLevel Debug \
  --Description "My service info" \
  --DisplayName "My Server" \
  --Install 'C:\Program Files\MyServer\tomcat\bin\tomcat8.exe' \
  --LogPath 'C:\ProgramData\MyServer\tomcat\logs' \
  --ServiceUser 'myuser@contoso.com' \
  --ServicePassword test123 \
  --StdOutput auto \
  --StdError auto \
  --StartImage "C:\Program Files\MyServer\java\bin\java.exe" \
  --Startup auto \
  --StartMode exe \
  --StopMode exe \
  --StartParams start \
  --StopParams stop \
  --StartClass org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap \
  --StopClass org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap \
  --JvmOptions "-Dcmb.productdir=C:\Program Files\MyServer;-Dcmb.datadir=C:\ProgramData\MyServer;-Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\MyServer\tomcat;-Dcatalina.base=C:\ProgramData\MyServer\tomcat;-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\MyServer\tomcat\endorsed;-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\ProgramData\MyServer\tomcat\temp;-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager;-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\ProgramData\MyServer\tomcat\conf\logging.properties" \
  --JvmMs 256m \
  --JvmMx 1024m \
  --Classpath "C:\Program Files\MyServer\tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\MyServer\tomcat\bin\tomcat-juli.jar;C:\ProgramData\MyServer\resource;C:\Program Files\MyServer\resource"
```

In place of --ServiceUser and --ServicePassword I've also tried --User and --Password.  The failure is the same.

When I use --ServiceUser and go into Windows Services, find MyServer -> Properties -> LogOn -> This Account shows myuser@contoso.com.  When I use --User the properties panel has This Account as blank and Local System selected.

The myuser@contoso.com is an AD account.  On the local system where tomcat8 service is being added it has a group policy which gives it "Log On as a service".

I also verified that myuser@contoso.com is a valid account and the password matches by running this from a cmd prompt:

```
runas /noprofile /user:myuser@contoso.com notepad
Enter the password for myuser@contoso.com: test123
```

When I look at the Apache Commons procsrv C code I found this section which appears to be where the "Failed to create process" and then "The user name or password is incorrect" errors are triggered:

```
  if (!LogonUserW(szUsername,
                    NULL,
                    szPassword,
                    bLogonAsService ? LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE : LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK,
                    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                    &hUser)) {
        /* Logon Failed */
        apxLogWrite(APXLOG_MARK_SYSERR);
        return NULL;
    }
```

I wrote a simple C program with the above code and verified that if szPassword is NULL or not a match for the AD password for myuser@contoso.com I get "The user name or password is incorrect".

I can't think of anything else to try.  I'm stuck. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Apache Commons Daemon code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/daemon/trunk/src/native/windows/apps/prunsrv/prunsrv.c?revision=1237767&view=markup), I see that the only time that Tomcat actually needs the user details is when it's starting as a separate executable - i.e. when you have installed it as `-StartMode exe`.

Looking at the way that tomcat is normally installed in [service.bat](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/bin/service.bat), I see that this uses the JNI form of invocation - i.e. `-StartMode jvm`.  This will not go through the problematic path and so should avoid your user/password problem.

Alternatively, if you actually need Tomcat to run as a separate executable...  You can see in the same Apache Commons code linked above that it gets all its data from a combination of the command-line and the Windows Registry.  Since you have installed your service with no command-line parameters, it will try to find the user and password in the registry.  In addition, since you have not specified the `User` or `Password` on installation, it won't have saved them off to the registry either.  It is therefore pulling in empty values.

So, you have two possible ways that you can resolve this problem:

1. Start up (and stop) in JVM mode, using `-StartMode jvm` when you install the service.
2. Specify **both** forms of `User` and `Password` when installing your service.  This should put the extra data into the Registry and so make it available when the service tries to start.

Comment: The combination of --StartMode jvm and using both forms of --User and --Password fixed the problem!  Thank you Peter!  You rock!

Comment: I also try all those that you try but i am not able get success on it. can you please help me on it? I am trying to solve from last 3 days. I also ask question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806461/how-to-impersonate-tomcat-window-service-at-run-time

Answer (score 0):

You used an incorrect parameter name for your username and password.

**--ServiceUser 'myuser@contoso.com'  --ServicePassword 
test123**

It should be:

**--User 'myuser@contoso.com'
--Password test123**

OR

Try this https://superuser.com/a/842867

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried --User/--Password as I noted in my very long description.  :) I also previously tried the suggestions in the link provided.  All result in the same error "The user name or password is incorrect".

Answer (score 0):

When entering commands, you should do so as Administrator. E.g. from Windows start menu, type in `cmd`, right click on the `cmd.exe` or Command Prompt it gives you, and `select Run as administrator`.

### Install TomcatN as a service:

Just run tomcat's `c:\path\to\TomcatN\bin\service.bat` and give it a service name to use, i.e. `Tomcat8`. Or,

```
sc Create TomcatN binPath= "c:\path\to\TomcatN\bin\tomcatN.exe" displayName= "Apache Tomcat N"
```

### Set the service to run as a specific user:

Most of the time you don't need this. But sometimes you need to access the Windows network as a registered user. For example, if you are taking advantage of some Active Directory functionality. It might work to use the following:

```
C:\path\to\tomcatN\bin\service.bat install TomcatN --user=George --password=abc123
```

But probably not. You can configure the service manually instead.

### Manually configure the service to use a specific username and password:

From the Windows command prompt, you can use the services configurator. Some commands of interest:

```
sc
sc query TomcatN
sc qc TomcatN
sc config TomcatN obj= "MyHostName\George" password= "abc123"
```

Take care to note the space that comes after the equal signs in that last command.

### Ensure the user has permissions:

Enter the `gpedit.msc` command. In the GUI that appears, navigate to

```
Local Computer Policy                  | ...
    - Computer Configuration           | ...
        - Windows Settings             | []Log on as a service
            - Security Settings        | ...
                User Rights Assignment | ...
```

Double-click on `Log on as a service` and `Add User or Group....` Type the shorthand for the username you want the service to use into the field, click `Check Names`, and press `OK`.

### Confirm that TomcatN is running as intended:

You can use the following commands to start, stop, and check the status of the service:

```
net start TomcatN
net stop TomcatN
sc query TomcatN
```

### Checking that the login works as intended

Make sure you've started the service running. Open Windows Task Manager and view the Processes tab. Click on `Show processes from all users` if necessary. `TomcatN` should be listed, with the username you specified next to it.

Credit goes to @[andrewk](https://superuser.com/users/391853/andrewk)

### Resource Link:

1. [How do I run Tomcat service as a specific user in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/842866/how-do-i-run-tomcat-service-as-a-specific-user-in-windows)
2. [Run Tomcat Service as Different User on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/301864/run-tomcat-service-as-different-user-on-windows-7)

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed response.  I do appreciate it.  I have previously tried all of the above except using service.bat.  I cannot use service.bat as I need to set a number of options like --StartImage "C:\Program Files\MyServer\java\bin\java.exe".  The "tomcat8.exe ..." command line I listed is based on what service.bat runs anyway.  Obviously I have changed a few options.  Yes, I am running the "tomcat8.exe ..." in a cmd running as Administrator.